# Como printar elementos de uma pilha?

Tags: python, estrutura-de-dados, stack

Estou com problema de formatação de saída desse programa. Abaixo segue o trecho do código que faz a impressão da pilha, em seguida segue a img do problema

```
def __repr__(self):
    r = ""
    pointer = self.top
    while(pointer):
        r = r + str(pointer.data) + " "
        pointer = pointer.next
    return r
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só por curiosidade o que seria esse `self.top`?

Comment: acredito que o topo da pilha

Comment: Beleza é topo da pilha, mas esse topo da pilha é instancia de que classe?

Comment: `class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = None
        self._size = 0`               tá falando da classe da pilha?

Comment: kkkk desculpa, não manjo muito estou pagando ed pela 1ª vez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisar adicionar o método [strip()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-strip/). Para remover espaços em branco no inicio e final das strings geradas.

Uma possível solução, utilizando o seu código, seria:

```
def __repr__(self):
    r = ""
    pointer = self.top
    while(pointer):
        r = r + str(pointer.data) + " "
        pointer = pointer.next
    return r.strip()
```

Desta forma a saída esperada será igual a resposta obtidas do seu programa.

Comment: grato pela resposta